# Is impaired used with performance and consciousness?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if I can use impaired with **performance** and **consciousness**.
Here is the context:

> Impaired performance and consciousness are associated with increased sleepiness and can endanger the health and safety of workers.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can; that's a very common phrasing.

Comment: I don't think consciousness can be impaired, maybe because I don't think of many degrees of consciousness - just conscious, semi-conscious, and unconscious.

Comment: Yes you can. You could also use "impaired judgment".

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use impaired in this way. Judging by this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impaired%20performance%2C%20impaired%20consciousness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpaired%20performance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpaired%20consciousness%3B%2Cc0), it has seen a significant rise in popularity since the 1960's when used with both performance and consciousness.

Comment: Looking at the NGram, "impaired consciousness" seems to have a particular medical or legal definition of brain damage or mental illness, and there are some instances of sentences like 'mobility-impaired consciousness' (yikes - what the heck does that actually mean?) where impaired isn't modifying consciousness. I think 'alertness' might be better than consciousness, but it's hard to tell without more context.